# Ice Cream Sandwich - Custom fonts issue.

Tags: android, fonts, truetype

I customised all fonts in my app, everything is working properly on 2.2, and 2.3, but on 4.0, fonts are much thinner. How to fix it? I also have another font (helvetica) which is a .otf file and it working alright. Other fonts are .ttf!

[image: Example:]

(on top 2.2, bottom ice cream sandwich 4.0).

Comment: Have you checked on the real device ? This might be a rendering issue of the emulator.

Comment: Do you use the same dpis? The same text size?

Comment: Did you try to convert the ttf to otf to see the result? It is a shot in the dark but if you can't debug it, circumvent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[his](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643141/his) has right, I just need to convert .ttf to .otf and it works fine. Thanks.